# Hooking [NSEvent mouseLocation] at the system level?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, assembly, nsevent

So I'd like to be able to hook [NSEvent mouseLocation] at the system level, and basically have it return what I'd like.

This is due to being unable to send mouse events to games, since they fire of [NSEvent mouseLocation] to get the location of the mouse pointer.

Anyone have any pointers on where I could poke around?

Answer (score 0):

Use even taps, this way you can modify any event in the system before it reaches the application.

This requires "access for assistive devices" to be enabled and this requires the carbon framework.

Comment: The [CGEvent functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/) are not Carbon; they are in the ApplicationServices framework, and they are included if you link against Cocoa.